# Uncaught TypeError: Unable to read undefined properties (reading '$store')

Tags: vue.js, authentication, typeerror, vue-router, store

```
Login Vue
<template>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
              <label>Kullanıcı Adı</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                v-model="userdata.username"
              />
              <br />

              <label>Şifre</label>
              <input class="form-control" v-model="userdata.password" />
              <br />
              <button class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive } from "vue";

const userdata = reactive({
  username: "",
  password: "",
});

function loginAction() {
 
  this.$store.dispatch("loginPost", userdata.value);
  this.$router.push({ path: "/city" });
}

function onSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  loginAction();
}
</script>

<style></style>
store kısmı     import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cities: [],
    user: {},
    token: null,
  },
  getters: {},

  mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
     
      state.token = token;

      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    },
    setUser(state, user) {
      
      state.user = user;

      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async login({ commit }, credentials) {
      const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7254/api/Auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        commit("setUser", data.user);
        commit("setToken", data.token);
      }
      return response.ok;
    },
  },
});
store js

import { createStore } from "vuex";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cities: [],
    user: {},
    token: null,
  },
  getters: {},

  mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
    
      state.token = token;

      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    },
    setUser(state, user) {
     
      state.user = user;

      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async login({ commit }, credentials) {
      const response = await fetch("https://localhost:7254/api/Auth/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.ok) {
        commit("setUser", data.user);
        commit("setToken", data.token);
      }
      return response.ok;
    },
  },
});

router js

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import { city } from "@/components/City.vue";
import { Login } from "@/components/Login.vue";
import { home } from "@/components/Home.vue";
const routes = [
  {
    name: "login",
    path: "/login",

    component: Login,
  },
  {
    name: "city",
    path: "/city",

    component: city,
  },
  {
    name: "home",
    path: "/",

    component: home,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, next) => {
  // localStorage'daki JWT token'ı ve kullanıcı bilgilerini kontrol edin
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

  // JWT token veya kullanıcı bilgisi yoksa, giriş sayfasına yönlendirin

  // Eğer zaten giriş sayfasına gidiyorsak, yönlendirmeyi iptal edin
  if (!token || !user) {
    next({ path: "/login" });
  }
  next();
});

export default router;

main js

import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import store from "../src/store";
import router from "../src/router";
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
createApp(App).use(router).use(store).mount("#app");

Home vue

<!-- eslint-disable vue/multi-word-component-names -->
<template>
  <h1>anasayfa Vue</h1>
  <city />
  <login />
</template>

<script setup>
import city from "@/components/City.vue";
import login from "@/components/Login.vue";
</script>

<style></style>
```

For example, when the page loads, I want it to go directly to the login page because in my router js file, I wrote the condition that it goes directly to the login page if there is no token and user with beforeEach, but it does not work, it gives this warning console log [Vue Router warn]: Unexpected error while initializing the router: TypeError: next is not a function After filling out and submitting the form, I get the following error Uncaught TypeError: Unable to read undefined properties (reading '$store')

Answer (score 0):

first of all "this" doesn't refer to vue instance ,it refers to loginAction block,use arrow function instead ,secondly due to docs you should use  useStore() method to get store in vue 3 Composition [api](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/migrating-to-4-0-from-3-x.html#new-usestore-composition-function)